# Ask for post author approval of edits even when one has full edit privileges

Tags: feature-request, edits

I just finished my first ever edit of someone else's answer. (I didn't have to go through the review queue, since I have over 2000 reputation. So I never experienced the review queue, this being my first edit of someone else's post.)

**I don't want to be preachy or 'change the SO culture / customs'**

I just would like to say - humbly, *it feels wrong to me*. It feels like tying someone else's shoelaces. I am aware that feelings are not arguments. I'm also aware that I can't choose feelings; feelings choose me. Could SO help me deal with what might be a legitimate concern, or just silly over-cautiousness?

I was thinking about something like an **"ask author first"** button. If I edit someone else's post I want that there is a button that I can press, and if I do so my changes are not directly committed to be visible by the public. Instead the original poster is prompted to accept or reject the changes, and while that is pending, the old version is what the public sees.

Such a button could possibly act as the 'kids training wheels' encouraging the pathologically bashful (?) to dare such edits when  the editor would otherwise be too scared about how the edit will be received, so I thought.

[related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103270/can-i-submit-an-edit-for-approval-after-earning-2k-reputation) (thx Robert Longson)

Comment: I don't think this will happen. Once you have a privilege, you're trusted to use it properly. Similarly, users have requested to make it possible to not unilaterally close a question as a duplicate once getting a gold badge, and that's been denied. If you want a second opinion, I recommend popping into chat, usually a tag-specific one can help most.

Comment: If you are not certain of the edit, just do not click on "submit". That's the "humblest" path, and it should be exactly the same if you have full-edit privileges or if your edits have to be peer-reviewed. And the post author can always roll-back the edit if they disagree with it.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103270/can-i-submit-an-edit-for-approval-after-earning-2k-reputation

Comment: @ErikA Suppose I have the privilege of being a certified heart surgeon, who is trusted to use his medical skills properly. Would you find it unreasonable if I demand - no matter how urgent an operation might be - that prospective patients are asked first, before they are subjected to be operated on, and not ever abducted into the hospital? Not even saying, you're a bad doctor / person if you have your patients abducted, if you think you can save an extra life. Just saying, I don't want to be part of that. And that, you find unreasonable? I find that extremely hard to fathom.

Comment: There are a zillion trillion posts where you can be sure that the asker & everyone else is going to agree that your edit is a definite big improvement. Edit those.

Comment: @yivi: if I don't hit "submit", how will the original poster see the changes I have suggested? Maybe the feature already exists, and I'm too dumb to see it?! Please elaborate what you're saying, sounds promising.

Comment: This  is not a matter of humility. It is a matter of not having confidence in yourself. If you aren't confident that your edits are good, **don't submit them**. Don't try and put the burden on someone else to review them. If you aren't sure about your own edits, why would you expect a couple of reviewers to be confident about them?

Comment: Logically, if you do not hit submit, nobody will see your edit. Makes sense: if you do not feel certain of an edit, just don't make the edit. Again, that you have full edit privileges or not makes no difference.

Comment: @mathheadinclouds The OP can always roll back the comment (in contrast to heart surgery, that's difficult to undo), and is not asked when it's reviewed, random people are. Your analogy goes wrong in many ways. If I'm a certified heart surgeon, I'm on call, and I need to perform an emergency surgery, it's unreasonable for me to demand a colleague to review the case with me and decide I'm making a good decision for a certain surgical approach, while for a resident that's very reasonable thing to ask. That's the more proper analogy here.

Comment: I'm asking for an "option to ask". Please read my @ErikA comment, the heart surgeon comparison. Speaking in that metaphor, I will not perform heart surgery, unless the patient has agreed. Even if they die. This is what I will do, and I really do not care if you like that or not. Not saying that you're bad if you save a life and operate without consent. Just saying, I'm not doing that, no matter what you say. If I do not have the "ask first" button, somewhere between 99% and 100% of suggested edits I could make, I just won't. No matter what you say. Just so you know.

Comment: "don't knock on doors, just go right in. If you're not sure you'll be welcome, then just don't go in. Use some other door then, and go in there, without knocking." Sounds absurd? That what you all sound to me. I want to knock. Not even saying everybody should knock. Just that I want to do it. And I'm the weird one??? nope. I can't knock, I won't edit posts. Ever again. end of story.

Comment: You are asking for some way to knock on an *open door*. It doesn't work that way. If you aren't sure that you belong on the other side of that door, you shouldn't walk through. Don't try and push the burden off on someone else. We are each accountable for our own actions.

Comment: ... If you really, _really_ want to get your comment reviewed (it seems you're making this very dramatic), just open the question/answer in incognito/private browsing and make the edit, since that'll be on an anonymous account and will always get reviewed.

Comment: See this as an opportunity for personal growth. Try to become confident enough to and comfortable enough with changing some text on some interwebsite without second guessing it. You've had your trial period with it and mastered it. And it's really not the end of the world if you get it wrong once or twice.

Comment: PS (Similarly) Re "Just accept that it does to me." Nobody has denied that "it feels wrong to" you. So, why write that, as if we did? (Rhetorical.) It seems like you are making further negative unsound leaps to (wrong) conclusions/hypotheses there based on our talking about possibilities for consequent action and/or reframing/reinterpreting/rethinking. PS Until such a button, hope you can find some helpful options here & at the link.

Comment: @CodyGray: the "knocking on open door" thing, that was just what I needed to hear. Pure gold, thank you. If you have the time, could you please answer the question? I don't really want to accept my own answer.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because it implied that people with limited English skills were akin to 5-year olds. That's extremely unfair: many of our users do not have English as their native language. I felt that last edit you made was in bad faith and does not belong. Please do not put it back.

Comment: @CodyGray: I will not put it back, you're the boss. I most certainly did not mean to imply what you said I implied, and I don't think I did. Not being a native speaker myself, I take your word for it that did sound that way, albeit with big surprise. What I was trying to express is exactly the point that you made towards me when you were said I was putting the burden off to other people, so to show that I got your point (after a while), I reiterated it. The typo / not typo was just an example for something where the decision should be easy: am I competent to do the edit or not.

Comment: @CodyGray: I respectfully ask that you do not claim I "implied" things I did not imply. Let's just say I accidentally implied it. I can live with that. Not with "extremely unfair". Here you are implying intent on my part, which did not exist.

Comment: @CodyGray: I want to terminate my account.

Answer (score 18):

I believe you are over-thinking this, and the comparison with heart-surgeon kinda confirms the feeling.

As editors we are more like ants than surgeons. We are not dealing with life and death after years or decades of study and experience; but actually moving dirt and twigs around.

Each ant in the anthill needs to do its thing and be relatively confident on where it needs to go, and what needs doing.

One moves a bit of dirt around, other ants will come afterwards moving even more dirt around. If you are not sure about moving a particular twig somewhere, just don't. Some other ant will come around eventually and make their own judgement. And so it goes.

The anthill is never complete, and dirt-ownership is quite relative on this site.

Anyone who submits a post in this network needs to be aware that community-edition **is a thing**, and be grateful for it. When other users edit our posts **they are donating free labour to improve something we posted**.

On top of that: that there is a review process before you hit 2K is immaterial. When one submits an edit, one should be confident that the edit is an actual improvement to the post. Otherwise, you are just giving other users work when you are not confident of the work you did yourself.

And if an edit were approved on review, the post author would likely see the edit **after** it got reviewed, so the *"respect the author's will"* angle doesn't really work either. Even when you were below 2k and had to have your suggested edits reviewed by the community.

If you **really** want to ask for permission before submitting an edit, you can always post a comment under the post mentioning your intentions: E.g.: "*Do you mind if I fix the code's format? I find it hard to read. Also, a link to the docs wouldn't go amiss. I can edit this in if you don't object*".

Almost always, this is unnecessary; but nothing stops you from engaging the post author this way if it makes editing more comfortable for you.

Comment: "And if an edit gets approved, the post author is likely to see the edit after it is approved, so the "respect the author's will" angle doesn't really work either."
I changed the heading to reflect that the "author's will" is what matters to me, that the original poster is the one who's OK I want, and that I don't really want other users (who aren't the OP) to be burdened with reviewing edits. So that angle *does* work, but I mislead you with my bad heading.
I would like to edit your post by removing the paragraph I quoted, since, after I updated the heading, that paragraph is obsolete. OK?

Comment: according to your standards, I should have just gone ahead and removed that paragraph. Maybe you get my point now.

Comment: No, it's not OK, but not because editing is wrong, but because it is wrong to change a question fundamentally after it is answered.

Comment: I'm not rolling back the edit to the question simply because I believe the answer still stands, but making a change on a question that invalidates existing answers is not fair game.

Comment: hmmm. you think I should revert to the old question heading? I do get your point. I did not edit the question heading to make you look bad. I did it because that more accurately reflects what I am actually suggesting.

Comment: I don't mind. I believe the answer still stands. The point is the same.

Comment: I have not changed the question "fundamentally". I refined it. Do you disagree?

Comment: I still suggest that you remove that one sentence. ("and if and edit gets appro..") I think without that sentence, you're still making all the good points you're making, without referring to the small part of my question which I changed. But you don't want to make the edit. And I perfectly understand why. Because it does make sense with regard to the old version of the question. So we agree to disagree on your post. I would remove that sentence, you wouldn't. And all I'm saying is, I want that your opinion is what counts, because you're the author, so I won't remove that sentence.Or Should I?

Comment: because I *DO* think it's a better post without that sentence, and if I would subscribe to the "ant philosophy" I *would* remove it.

Comment: You should never change the intent of a post. If an edit of yours change the intent of a post, is wrong, and would be rejected on review or rolled back by the post author.

Comment: hmmm. If that one sentence were removed, would that change the intent??? I think not. Anyway, it's a complete non-issue, because I will not remove that sentence.

Comment: You suggest to do "Do you mind if I fix the code's format?" in a comment. My problem with that is that the edit might involve formatting, and that you can't efficiently convey what it would look like in such a comment. That is actually one of the reasons why everybody suggests doing the edit, and the post owner can then revert, it's more efficient. I get that. So doing the edit is better than writing that comment. I actually agree. but still that button (see here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103270/can-i-submit-an-edit-for-approval-after-earning-2k-reputation), what's wrong with it

Answer (score -4):

I still think it's a good (or, non-bad) idea, but it's certainly not the most pressing or urgent issue.

If the author of a post wants the post to be non-editable (which is a legitimate concern), that can easily  be achieved simply by putting the post (or a portion of it) on their own website. (((Like this: [here is a mini article (about 1 page) I just put onto my github page](https://mathheadinclouds.github.io/yadayada/SOwikiStarTreck.html), loosely related to the question - It's somewhat loo long for this answer, plus, I do not want it be edited.)))

By not doing that, the author has (implicitly) agreed to whatever editing is customary on SO. (Actually, in a certain (obnoxious) sense, the author has *explicitly* agreed - 'woot ?? you no read our sacred yada yada - you click ok and check box, yo' - that sense)

It's of course a little more work to put the post (or part of it) onto an external source, but that is
exactly "how it should be": if you spent a lot of work to make the perfect post, the little extra work of
putting it somewhere external in order to protect it from doofus-improvements won't make much of a difference
in terms of total work spent; and if you didn't spend a lot of work, chances are, it is not the perfect post,
and it is a good thing that it will/might be edited - after all, SO is packed with people just longing to do something meaningful.

I had to think about it for a while, but @Cody Gray has a point with the "knocking on open doors" analogy, which is why the button is less useful than I initially thought.

It's not wrong not wanting to intrude. Not at all. Neither is there anything wrong with not wanting to be intruded upon. What's wrong (with my logic) is this: when you *do* encounter an open door, you simply *cannot* simultaneously make 100% certain that the homeowner will not be annoyed by your request, and still make that request. And a loud door bell on that open door certainly won't make this impossibility possible. And I - subconsciously - wanted this impossibility. Or maybe not. In any case, I can't be mad about people thinking that this kind of nonsense is what I thought, because, from how I put forward the question, that assumption is not far fetched.

The original author will either be happy or not with some 'foreign' edits. Whether or not those edits are (between the edit and the owner seeing them) visible to the public, that is a minor issue. The point is that it takes time for the owner to review and to say yes or no, and no button or whatever can make that time requirement go away. I cannot "be non-intrusive" and simultaneously make and not make the edit (or, suggest the edit, but not take up some of the time of the owner.) That is wishful thinking.

And wishful thinking is not acceptable.

That is my take-away.

Your take-away probably should be something totally different.

Comment: I'd say that we're all *explicitly* agreeing that others may edit our posts based on the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) and [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).